# How to generates a list which elements are at a fix distance from a desired list

Tags: python, combinations, iterable, hamming-distance

I have a list of possibilities and a desired input:

```
possibles = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
desired = [20, 30, 40]
```

I want to generate the close by lists. Example:

```
# Distance of 1 (i.e. 1 element changes to a close-by)
[30, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 40]
[20, 30, 30]
[20, 30, 50]

# Distance of 2:
[40, 30, 40]
[30, 30, 50]
[30, 40, 40]
...
```

My current version is only varying one element at a time, thus, as soon as the distance is above 1, I'm missing a lot of combination.

```
def generate_close_by(possibles, desired):
    for k in range(1, 4):
        for i, elt in enumerate(desired):
            id = possibles.index(elt)

            new = desired[:]
            if id < len(possibles)-k-1:
                new[i] = possibles[id+k]
                yield (new)

            if id > k:
                new[i] = possibles[id-k]
                yield (new)

# Output
[30, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 40]
[20, 30, 50]
[20, 30, 30]
[40, 30, 40]
[20, 50, 40]
[20, 30, 60]
[50, 30, 40]
[20, 60, 40]
[20, 30, 70]
```

I'm quite sure a module should already exist to do this kind of iteration (itertools?), could you point me to the write function?

Thanks.

***EDIT:***

Update on the tries...

I'm trying to generate a list the same size of desired in which each element correspond to how much I have to move the element of desired.

```
desired = [20, 30, 40]
# Distance of 1:
distance = [1, 0, 0]
distance = [0, 1, 0]
distance = [0, 0, 1]
distance = [-1, 0, 0]
distance = [0, -1, 0]
distance = [0, 0, -1]
```

And then plan was to try to create the new list, and if it can't (out of bounds), it just continues. Not working yet, but might be a good approach.

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic behind the desired output

Comment: @U9-Forward Order doesn't matter, and I just wrote 3 examples hand made... Basicly I want all combinations at a Hammnig distance of 1, then all combinations at a Hammnig distance of 2, and then of 3. The distance corresponds to: sum of how much the elements were "moved". That's my variable `k`

Comment: is `desired` always subset of `possibles` ?

Comment: @SeljukGülcan Yes desired is always a subset of possibles. Size 2 to 6. And possibles is always ordered.

Comment: is distance always up to 2, or can it change?

Comment: @SeljukGülcan You can set a max if you want, I don't expect that I will need combinations with a distance above 3.

Comment: What about `[20, 20, 40]`?

Comment: @tobias_k Good remark, didn't even noticed it. Distanc of 1, should have been outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I will show a more long winded approach that can be more easily generalizable.

I first write down the problem.

```
possible_pts = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
starting_pt_in_idx = [0, 1, 2]
distance = 2
```

There are 3 axes that can "change". I first find the combinations of axis changes.

```
N = len(starting_pt_in_idx)
axis = list(range(N))

import itertools
axismoves = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(axis, distance))
print(axismoves)
```

Next, we bin it. For example, if I see axis-0 appearing twice, it becomes [2,0,0].

```
abs_movements = []
for combi in axismoves:
    move_bin = [0] * N
    for i in combi:
        move_bin[i] += 1
    abs_movements.append(move_bin)
print(abs_movements)
```

The above gave the absolute movements. To find the actual movement, we must take into consideration the change can be positive or negative along that axis.

```
import copy
actual_movements = []
for movement in abs_movements:
    actual_movements.append(movement)
    for i, move in enumerate(movement):
        if move != 0:
            _movement = copy.deepcopy(movement)
            _movement[i] = - move
            actual_movements.append(_movement)
print(actual_movements)
```

The final step is to translate the index into actual positions. So first we write this helper function.

```
def translate_idx_to_pos(idx_vect, points):
    idx_bounds = [0, len(points) - 1]
    pos_point = [0] * len(idx_vect)
    for i, idx_pos in enumerate(idx_vect):
        if idx_pos < idx_bounds[0] or idx_pos > idx_bounds[1]:
            return None
        else:
            pos_point[i] = points[idx_pos]
    return pos_point
```

Using the actual movements to act on the starting point index, then translating it back to the positions.

```
from operator import add
final_pts = []
for movement in actual_movements:
    final_pt_in_idx = list(map(add, starting_pt_in_idx, movement))
    final_point = translate_idx_to_pos(final_pt_in_idx, possible_pts)
    if final_point is not None:
        final_pts.append(final_point)

print(final_pts)
```

This gives

```
[40, 30, 40]
[30, 40, 40]
[30, 20, 40]
[30, 30, 50]
[30, 30, 30]
[20, 50, 40]
[20, 40, 50]
[20, 20, 50]
[20, 40, 30]
[20, 30, 60]
[20, 30, 20]
```

Comment: I like this approch on the ids and movement :) Thanks

Comment: Actually what I was trying to achieve (c.f. Edit). Works great, and fast!

Comment: Glad you like it. And indeed it is fast because it enumerates only the needed combinations and builds from there.

Comment: Yes :) Exactly what I was trying to achieve. I did some slight changes to turn that into a generator, and it's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, `itertools` is gonna be really useful here. What you want is find all subsets of desired length of the `possibles` list WITH duplicates, and the function that does that is `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

possibles = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
desired = [20, 30, 40]

def fake_hamming(cur, desired, possibles):
    assert len(cur) == len(desired)

    hamm = 0
    for i in range(len(cur)):
        assert cur[i] in possibles
        assert desired[i] in possibles
        hamm += abs(possibles.index(cur[i]) - possibles.index(desired[i]))

    return hamm

def generate_close_by(desired, possibles, dist):
    all_possible_lists = product(possibles, repeat=len(desired))
    return [l for l in all_possible_lists if fake_hamming(l, desired, possibles) == dist]

print(generate_close_by(desired, possibles,1))
>>> [(20, 20, 40), (20, 30, 30), (20, 30, 50), (20, 40, 40), (30, 30, 40)]
```

**Edit** There you go, changed combinations for product (see @tobias_k comment below), and also here is the `fake_hamming` function xD
Also it is true that it will be slow for big lists, but this is the most generic way to do it

Comment: That is the part I've got, I've got some issues with the hamming distance sadly.

Comment: For small lists for combinations, this is probably the simplest, but for longer lists (say 100 possibilities and 5 elements in desired) this quickly becomes infeasible.

Comment: Oh wait I just re read your question, that's not a real hamming distance that you want

Comment: @Zuma maybe... I'm not really sure about what it is ^^'

Comment: @tobias_k possibles is quite small, < 20 elts, and desired up to 6 elts. Issue is that I'm going to perform this computation of close-by on thousands of elements.

Comment: Hamming distance counts the number of different elements in two sequences ;)

Comment: @Zuma So it's a bit more complex indeed.

Comment: And your outputs can contain several times the same element ?

Comment: @Mathieu Even then it's quite a list to filter: 20**6 is 64,000,000. (Also, it should not be `combinations` but `product`, as elements can appear more then once, and order does matter.)

Comment: @tobias_k Not an issue. I need a generator so that I can break out early. True I need product.

Comment: @Mathieu see my edited answer, it does what you want I think

Comment: @Mathieu So does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def distribute(number, bucket):
  if bucket == 1:
    yield [number]
    if number != 0:
      yield [-1 * number]
  elif number == 0:
    yield [0]*bucket
  else:
    for i in range(number+1):
      for j in distribute(number-i, 1):
        for k in distribute(i, bucket-1):
          yield j+k

def generate(possibles, desired, distance):
  for index_distance_tuple in distribute(distance, len(desired)):
    retval = desired[:]
    for i, index in enumerate(index_distance_tuple):
      if index + i < 0 or index + i >= len(possibles):
        break
      retval[i] = possibles[index + i]
    else:
      yield retval
```

For distance 1:

```
for i in generate(possibles, desired, 1):
  print(i)
```

Output :

```
[30, 30, 40]
[20, 40, 40]
[20, 20, 40]
[20, 30, 50]
[20, 30, 30]
```

For distance 2 :

```
for i in generate(possibles, desired, 2):
  print(i)
```

Output :

```
[40, 30, 40]
[30, 40, 40]
[30, 20, 40]
[30, 30, 50]
[30, 30, 30]
[20, 50, 40]
[20, 40, 50]
[20, 40, 30]
[20, 20, 50]
[20, 20, 30]
[20, 30, 60]
[20, 30, 20]
```

Comment: Misunderstanding somewhere. [30, 30, 40] is indeed at a distance of 1 since the value 20 is changed to 30 (1 changed to a value at a distance of 1 in possibles). But the following are at further distance. [50, 30, 40] is at d  = 2, [50, 30, 40] at a distance of 3..

Comment: I see, I completely misunderstood. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Mathieu, I edited the answer. Can you check if it is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive approach: Keep track of the remaining distance and generate combinations of just the relevant elements.

```
def get_with_distance(poss, des, dist, k=0):
    if k < len(des):
        i = poss.index(des[k])
        for n in range(-dist, dist+1):
            if 0 <= i + n < len(poss):
                for comb in get_with_distance(poss, des, dist - abs(n), k+1):
                    yield [poss[i + n]] + comb
    elif dist == 0:
        yield []
```

This can still run into a few "dead-ends" if there is still `dist` remaining, but the `des` list is empty, but overall, this will check much fewer combinations than generating all the combinations up-front and checking their distance afterwards.

If the list of possible elements is longer, you might want to create a `dict` mapping elements to their index first, so you don't have to do `poss.index(first)` each time.

Example:

```
possibles = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
desired = [20, 30, 40]
for x in get_with_distance(possibles, desired, 2):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
[20, 20, 30]
[20, 20, 50]
[20, 30, 20]
[20, 30, 60]
[20, 40, 30]
[20, 40, 50]
[20, 50, 40]
[30, 20, 40]
[30, 30, 30]
[30, 30, 50]
[30, 40, 40]
[40, 30, 40]
```